# Why HAProxy won't listen on port 80?

Tags: linux, configuration, bind, load-balancing, haproxy

Fresh machine, no http servers are running (no httpd, no lighttpd, no nginx)

```
$ netstat -nat | grep 80 | grep LISTEN
```

yields nothing...

Here's my HAProxy conf, what can be the reason for HAProxy not to

```
global
        maxconn 72000
        daemon

defaults
        mode    http
        timeout connect 4000ms
        timeout client 60000ms
        timeout server 30000ms


frontend my_frontend
         bind *:80
         default_backend cdn

backend cdn
       server cdn1 10.177.0.17:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn2 10.177.1.92:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn3 10.177.1.147:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn4 10.177.1.202:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check

       server cdn4 10.177.1.202:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn5 10.177.1.211:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn6 10.177.1.93:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn7 10.177.1.230:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn8 10.177.0.7:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn9 10.177.0.196:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn10 10.177.1.82:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn11 10.177.0.124:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn12 10.177.1.142:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn13 10.177.1.58:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn14 10.177.1.137:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn15 10.177.1.169:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn16 10.177.0.187:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn17 10.177.1.95:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
       server cdn18 10.177.1.123:80 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
```

running haproxy-1.4.13 from source.

When I try to start it I get this error

```
[ALERT] 084/220004 (2409) : Starting frontend my_frontend: cannot bind socket
```

Answer (score 4):

add global config parameter called user

```
user nobody
```

or some less privileged user. Still you need to start as root, but after acquiring the port process itself will reduce the user/privileges to nobody.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried starting haproxy with the root user and it worked.
I'm not sure if it's a good idea to run it under root though.

Comment: Normally, only root can open "privileged" ports - numbered below 1024. A well behaved unix program opens any ports it needs and then drops to to another user id.

Answer (score -1):

haproxy can run under some other user. such as nobody..

Comment: its a comment yar not the answer